# Wait for an Observable or boolean in method

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an AuthGuard which I want to check my authentication status in my App.

Simplified it should work like this:

- if there is an `access_cookie`, return true
- if there is no `access_cookie` and no `refresh_cookie`, return false
- if there is no `access_cookie`, but a `refresh_cookie`, request a new `access_cookie` and on success, return true

However, returning plain true or false works of course, but the request for a new `access_cookie` is an `Observable<boolean>`.

My AuthGuard:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    ...
    const result = this.auth.checkCredentials(scopes);
    console.log(result);
    ....
}
```

The `checkCredentials()` (simplified):

```
checkCredentials(): boolean{
    if (!this.cookieService.check('access_token')) {
        if(this._getRefreshToken(){
            try {
              this.refresh().subscribe(
                result=> {
                  return result;
                },
                error => {
                  return false;
                });
            } catch (e) {
              return false;
            }
       }
    }

    return true;
 }
```

The `refresh` Obeservable

```
refresh(): Observable<boolean> {

    if (this._getRefreshToken() && !this.cookieService.check('access_token')) {
      const oauth2_token_endpoint = TOKEN_URL;
      const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(CLIENT_ID + ':' + CLIENT_SECRET),
      });
      const body = 'grant_type=' + GrantType.REFRESH + '&refresh_token=' + this._getRefreshToken();

      return this.http.post<UserData>(oauth2_token_endpoint, body, {headers})
        .pipe(map(user => {
          if (user && user.access_token) {
            this._saveToken(user);
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        }));
    }

    return throwError('Refresh Token Error');
  }
```

The `checkCredentials()` gets executed, but it does not wait for the `refresh()` but instead returns `undefined` immediately.

Where am I missing something?

I am using Angular 8.2.14 and rxjs 6.4.0

Comment: Just return `this.refresh()` or use `map` operator to turn it into `Boolean`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: In the `canActivate` method, you can return a `boolean` as you said, but you can also return an `Observable<boolean>`, which makes things really easy. Just return `refresh()` and map it so it that that observable returns a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `checkCredentials` is not returning a result inside the nested `if` block, it also subscribes to the observable instead of returning it. Use `map` instead of `subscribe` and return the `Obserable`. You should also change the signature on the method for the return type so that it returns either `boolean` *or* `Observable<boolean>`.

```
checkCredentials(): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    if (!this.cookieService.check('access_token') && this._getRefreshToken()) {
      return this.refresh().pipe(map(
        result=> {
          return result;
        }, error => {
          return false;
        }));
    }
    return true;
}
```

*Not of interest: I combined your 2 `if` blocks into 1.*